# Sci-fi TV series where a man asks his opponent why repeatedly

Tags: story-identification, tv

In an episode of a sci-fi TV series, the main character asks his opponent (or antagonist) the simple question, why. When he receives an answer he again asks why, and this repeats I believe one final time. It is a classic attempt to outwit or unsettle an opponent.

I mistakenly assumed that this segment was in the original *Star Trek* episode "The Changeling" though there was an attempt by Kirk to unsettle his opponent Nomad but he didn't use the above line of questioning. I'm now thinking that it may have been an episode in the original *Doctor Who* with Tom Baker though its just as likely to be in *Star Trek*.

Comment: I thought at first this might be the prisoner episode The General... here is a clip. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljGH07Unfe8

Comment: There is a list of logic bomb scenes from Doctor Who on TV Tropes take a look and see if anything looks familiar... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LogicBomb

Comment: This happened often in Holmes and YoYo, the robot cop kept getting stuck in a loop https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmes_%26_Yoyo

Comment: @dominicfonde I believe that it is indeed "The General". Why did you change your mind?

Comment: @dominicfonde Incidentally, re the "Logic Bomb" trope - I think an issue of Doctor Who Magazine once reviewed a story in which a computer was programmed to spot this sort of trick and skip past trying to handle it. I think the reviewer described this computer capability as "ON CONUNDRUM JUMP". Do you remember reading anything like this?

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica sadly no, have not come across that. As to why I changed my mind it is more than twenty years since I saw that episode and when I reviewed the clip on youtube my memory of it was faulty enough for me to be unsure.

Comment: @DannyMcG As I recall, that only happened when someone asked Yoyo about his last assignment, which was "The bunco squad. The bunco squad. The bunco squad..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is:

[Star Trek S02E24 The Ultimate Computer](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6n5dys)

At 44:20 is the sequence I was looking for. Looking at "The Changeling" reminded me of "The Ultimate Computer" called M5 in the original Star Trek because of the similarity in the mechanical voices.

The Prisoner episode is a good guess as are some of the Dr. Who clips. Maybe I'll look at some of them later tonight.

Comment: He only asked "Why?" twice in the clip.

Comment: That's what made it difficult to recall.

Answer (score 16):

I believe this to be an episode of *The Prisoner* (1960s TV series starring Patrick McGoohan) called "The General".

During the episode, the main character (his name is never given, he's just called "Number Six") inputs the question "Why?" into a mainframe computer. The computer is one of the antagonists of the episode - it's a sort of allegory for rote learning and its failure to encourage critical thinking, but I digress. The computer is unable to handle the question, and is destroyed trying to process it.

After this has happened, the following verbal exchange occurs between Six and the current episode's authority figure ("Number Two"):

> Number Two:   What was the question?
>
> Number Six:   It's insoluble, for man or machine.
>
> Number Two:   What was it?
>
> Number Six:   W. H. Y. Question mark.
>
> Number Two:   Why?
>
> Number Six:   Why?
>
> Number Two:   ... Why?

There is a transcript of the episode [here](http://www.daviddeley.com/profdeley/prisonerthegeneral.htm).

Comment: So this is why Matlab does funny things when asked "why"?

Comment: @vsz You may be interested to know that on his TV show, Jools Holland asked his Apple II "Why?" And on the screen there came the reply "Why not?"

Comment: The prisoner is da bomb!111

Comment: @MarkRogers It also has a gnostic angle apparently: https://www.sbl-site.org/publications/article.aspx?ArticleId=802 ... hoping for a remake in Embassy of Equador.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica Jools Holland has indeed parodied The Prisoner. Are you referring to the episode of The Tube? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFDLi06MVK8

Comment: @dominicfonde I certainly am!